# Azure function app throws "database communication link failure" error and stops working

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

The HTTP triggered function app is built using Python 3.x and uses pyodbc with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server to communicate with the SQL server DB which has been deployed in the same resource group and the same region. The function app throws **('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')** error (used logs to validate) from time to time and returns an error as the response.

This issue gets immediately resolved once we re-deploy the function app and keeps working for a period of time and becomes apparent again (re-deployed yesterday evening due to the issue and worked fine until re-checked in the morning and the issue was there again). This function app was working as expected until a couple of days before when we released a newer version with some improvements.

We have the exact same function app (the latest version) and setup (including the DB) deployed in 2 other Azure directories (the Dev and Test instances) and they are working without a hitch. The only difference is the service tier (the production version uses a premium plan while the dev and test use consumption plans).

Tried disabling the "always on - keeping at least one function app instance running" feature on the premium plan to verify whether it's due to a DB session issue but that didn't work as well. Also added the IP of the function app in the DB whitelist just in case (The azure resources can access the DB feature is also on so, adding the IP of the function app is not mandatory I guess) and that didn't work too.

Any support or expertise on the subject matter would be appreciated

Comment: After contacting the MS support team and analyzing the app logs, it was verified that the platform is sound and there were no issues regarding the function app. After debugging the code, it was found out that after the connection initialization, I have not closed the connection explicitly whenever the function app came into a close state. After adding the connection.close() properly, the function app is running smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe and guess there will be a version mismatch on the ODBC driver/connector between server and client.

Or

it could be related to the usage limit of the Azure SQL database in the Production Slot. Could you please check if there is any like compute the size of the database usage and increase it if it is near to the Quota defined!

If the same error comes in a while, please email the Function logs data and invocation Id along with the error details to `azcommunity@microsoft.com` with your subscription ID as well as your function app name as Microsoft Azure Support will do the analysis to find the root cause on your Azure Function App - SQL DB Connection Error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've already contacted the MS support team and verified that the platform integrity is solid. Managed to resolve the issue myself after debugging.